# Message Text not getting displayed in AngularJS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am using ASP.NET with angular.

In the scripts folder i have 2 files - MoviesAngular.js and ListController.js

MoviesAngular.js

```
(function ()
{
    var app = angular.module("MoviesAngular", []);
}

)
```

ListController.js

```
    (function () {

    var app = angular.module("MoviesAngular",[])

    var ListController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello World";
    };

    app.controller("ListController", ListController);

}()
);
```

In the Index.html i have the following code:
@section scripts {

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Client/Scripts/MoviesAngular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Client/Scripts/ListController.js"></script>

    }
  <div ng-app="MoviesAngular">
    <div ng-controller="ListController">
       {{message}}
    </div>

</div>
```

However when i run the application i am not getting the text displayed as "Hello World" Where am i going wrong here.

Edited to include the other scenario where controller and app was defined seperately:(I was getting the error - Error: $injector:nomod
Module Unavailable). Then i modified the code as above.

MoviesAngular.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("MoviesAngular", []);


}()

);
```

ListController.js

```
(function (app) {

    var ListController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello World";
    };

    app.controller("ListController", ListController);
}(angular.module("MoviesAngular"))
);
```

Comment: Why are you declaring your app and controller inside a function?

Comment: If you are declaring the app in controller you don't need MoviesAngular.js

Comment: @squiroid nothing related to angular. one is for jQuery - Denying load of chrome-extension://gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio/js/jquery.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Comment: @sms when i declare seperately it throws an error failed to load module. i will edit my query

Comment: @user2010243 could you please verify angular files are loaded or not, because looks like it has been placed in some condition

Comment: Failed to load module will come only when your angular scripts are not loaded properly. But you have included angular.min.js. So it should not come. Please review for any syntax errors. You don't need to declare app and controller inside a function in normal js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine: I have tested this

ww.js

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module("MoviesAngular",[])

var ListController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello World";
};

app.controller("ListController", ListController);

}()
);
```

The view is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="ww.js"></script></head>
<body>
<div ng-app="MoviesAngular">
<div ng-controller="ListController">
   {{message}}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I do not find any error in your code. I am just changing the syntax of code. Try this.

```
 (function () {

    var app = angular.module("MoviesAngular",[])


    app.controller("ListController", function ($scope) {

    var ListController = function () {
        $scope.message = "Hello World";
    };
     ListController();
});

}()

);
```

Answer (score 0):

The IIFE in the MoviesAngular.js file not invoked in your example

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("MoviesAngular", []);
}()); // invoke function expression
```

`angular.module` with specified second parameter creates new module. In the ListController.js file you need to get already created module, thus remove second parameter from `angular.module`

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("MoviesAngular")

  var ListController = function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello World";
  };

  app.controller("ListController", ListController);

}());
```